# How to add logo in Top side in Mystile theme instead of Header Portion?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing a very big problem in my **woo commerce** site.

I use **Mystile theme** and I want my logo in Top portion of the home page ( In line with Search ). But by default it's coming in line with Menu portion. I am attaching the screenshot for your ready reference:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Er. Jitesh,

Did you try to check if there are options on it's theme options? I'm sure it would be handy as it is a theme from woocommer. If there are no options available for changing the logo position, you will need to dig into the physical file and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with custom customization into the theme files header.php
You need to call logo code into your top bar.
Open your header.php and find the class wrapper, then into wrapper there will be a div with id top call logo code into this div and it will look like some this. http://prntscr.com/f361zd

Comment: it's Ok, just chill

Answer (score 0):

Please Copy and paste the following code in your header.php file in mystile theme. Before changing code please take a copy of your orginal code

```
<?php
// File Security Check
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page!' );
}
?>
<?php
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the header section of all screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
global $woo_options, $woocommerce;
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_boxed_layout'] == 'true' ) echo 'boxed'; ?> <?php if (!class_exists('woocommerce')) echo 'woocommerce-deactivated'; ?>">
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title><?php woo_title(''); ?></title>
<?php woo_meta(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
    wp_head();
    woo_head();
?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php woo_top(); ?>

<div id="wrapper">



    <div id="top">
        <nav class="col-full" role="navigation">
                     <?php
                $logo = esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' );
                if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' ) { $logo = $woo_options['woo_logo']; }
                if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' && is_ssl() ) { $logo = preg_replace("/^http:/", "https:", $woo_options['woo_logo']); }
            ?>
            <?php if ( ! isset( $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] ) || $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] != 'true' ) { ?>
                <a id="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php } ?>

            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'top-menu' ) ) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'top-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
                if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
                    echo '<ul class="nav wc-nav">';
                    do_action( 'mystile_cart_nav' );
                    echo get_search_form();
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            ?>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /#top -->



    <?php woo_header_before(); ?>

    <header id="header" class="col-full">



        <hgroup>


            <h3 class="nav-toggle"><a href="#navigation"><mark class="websymbols">&#178;</mark> <span><?php _e('Navigation', 'woothemes'); ?></span></a></h3>

        </hgroup>

        <?php woo_nav_before(); ?>

        <nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">

            <?php
            if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fr', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
            } else {
            ?>
            <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
                <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item current_page_item'; ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'woothemes' ); ?></a></li>
                <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>
            </ul><!-- /#nav -->
            <?php } ?>

        </nav><!-- /#navigation -->

        <?php woo_nav_after(); ?>

    </header><!-- /#header -->

    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
```